# A particle moves with a central acceleration being projected from an apse at a distance $a$ with twice the velocity for a circle at that distance

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

> A particle moves with a central acceleration $\mu\left(r+\frac{2a^3}{r^2}\right)$, being projected from an apse at a distance $a$ with twice the velocity for a circle at that distance; find the other apsidal distance and show that the equation to the path is, $$\frac{\theta}{2}=\tan^{-1}(t\sqrt{3})-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\tan^{-1}\left(t\sqrt{\frac53}\right)$$

Here,

$$
\begin{align}
v\frac{dv}{dx}&=-\mu\left(x+\frac{2a^3}{x^2}\right)\\
vdv&=-\mu\left(x+\frac{2a^3}{x^2}\right)dx\\
\frac{V^2}{2}&=-\mu\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{2a^3}{x}\right)+C
\end{align}
$$

**Question:** I didn't understand the line, **"...being projected from an apse at a distance $a$ with twice the velocity for a circle at that distance"**. That's why couldn't get the initial values for this DE.

I knew that then need to solve the pedal equation, $$\frac{d^2u}{du^2}+u=\frac{f}{h^2u^2}$$
where $u=\frac1r$.

Any help will be appreciated. TIA.